# How to persist Fluid document data between Tinylicious sessions?

Tags: fluid-framework

When I restart Tinylicious, I can't seem to load a document that I created before the restart, without clearing the var/tmp folder, and losing data.

This issue manifests itself as `DeltaConnectionFailureToConnect` errors:

[image]

To repro this issue on [Fluid Brainstorm Example](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidExamples/), start:server, start:client, make some changes on the document, restart Tinylicious server, reload the same URL. It either fails to load at all(Tinylicious 0.2.x), or loads some previous state of the document (Tinylicious 0.3.x).

In my own project (using Fluid 0.34.3), I've repro'ed this issue with Tinylicious 0.3.10860 and 0.2.3810. However I couldn't even get it create a new document with Tinylicious 0.4.x due to some uknown error.

- Is default configuration "db.inMemory: true" the reason for this behavior?

I tried passing --db.inMemory false and later changing the default --db.path 'var/tmp/db', my config seems to be ignored (I don't see a *db* folder generated under var when I run Tinylicious), however, I seem to be able to open the docs, in clean state (all data I add in the previous session, is lost when I restart Tinylicious).

Could somebody clarify the guidance in [Tinylicious Storage](https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/main/server/tinylicious/README.md#storage) and explain:

- How to change default configuration of Tinylicious?
- How to persist Fluid document data between Tinylicious sessions?

Comment: Thanks for bringing these up @user101010 . There seem to be a collection of issues you are facing here. Can you please raise them as issues in the fluidframework GitHub and we can begin to address and prioritize them there. https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/issues/new/choose

Comment: Sure, I could raise issues, but I'd love to learn what I'm doing wrong (both config/ usage wise) so I'd appreciate some answers for the questions I raised here